# Setup Netbeans project on Jenkins

Tags: netbeans, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a Netbeans Project that I'm trying to build from Jenkins, using `ant`, in a linux environment. 
I have copied the `CopyLibStack.jar` to `/var/lib/Jenkins/nblibs/` and setup in the `ant` task with the following properties:

```
-Dj2ee.server.home="/var/lib/jenkins/tomcat/" 
-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=/var/lib/jenkins/nblibs/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

But it doesn’t work; it fails on a `<copyfiles>` task

If I install Jenkins on windows and set the properties to:

```
-Dj2ee.server.home="C:\Archivos de programa\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0" 
-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:\\.jenkins\\nblibs\\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

The project build without problems

If I run the `ant` task from the terminal with:

```
ant -file build.xml do-dist test -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath="/var/lib/jenkins/nblibs/copylibstask.jar" -Dj2ee.server.home="/var/lib/jenkins/tomcat/"
```

it builds fine too

I think that the problem is in the user `jenkins`, but I don't know how to fix it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which I have fixed :) (I'm using ubuntu 12.04). Find build.properties in ".netbeans/7.0" and look for the lib that you are missing... copy it to project.properties

Ex:

libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/opt/netbeans-7.0.1/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

libs.javaee-api-6.0.classpath=/opt/netbeans-7.0.1/enterprise/modules/ext/javaee-api-6.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found a recipe in this [link](http://warpedcore.net/2015/07/netbeans-ant-and-jenkins/) basically you have to have Netbeans installed on your server so you can reuse the build.xml generated by Netbeans.
Create a  file jenkins-build.xml at the same level as your build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="BioGatewayWS Stub" default="build" basedir=".">
    <!-- create private folders -->
    <mkdir dir="nbproject/private"/>
    <!--- set variables needed by Ant when outside of Netbeans -->
    <propertyfile file="nbproject/private/private.properties">
        <!--<entry key="user.properties.file" value="/opt/NetBeans8/build.properties"/>-->
        <entry key="user.properties.file" value="C:\Users\jm\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\build.properties"/>
    </propertyfile>
    <!-- Build targets - these just chain a call to the original build file-->
    <target name="build">
           <!-- <ant dir="${basedir}" target="build"/>-->
            <ant dir="${basedir}" target="default"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
            <ant dir="${basedir}" target="clean"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

and run Ant:

```
ant -file jenkins-build.xml clean
ant -file jenkins-build.xml build
```

Thanks to the original author matt